# Change style of rpivottable output

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

this is my shiny output of my rpivottable output.

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubWlr.jpg)

I want to have it like this. The combination of the frames on the left side to select the items.

[future](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0GUn.jpg)

What is the necessary option to change the style?

```
  output$table2 <- renderRpivotTable({
  rpivotTable(db2, aggregatorName = "Count")})
```

Thanks

Talcom

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Otherwise, it will be hard for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add whatever variables you want from db2 to be as rows and columns for example

```
rpivotTable(db2, aggregatorName = "Count",rows=c("Metric.ID", 
"Object.Name"),cols=c("Metric.Name","Grouping"))
```